# How should these ceiling repairs be finished?

Tags: drywall, repair, ceiling, texture

Need a 2nd opinion around the effectiveness of ceiling repair done.

This repair is made of 3 patches. Despite my request, the workman did not cut the ceiling to make it one patch and did 3 smaller patches. Leaving the last one not covering the water marks that were left.
Should I tear it own and get just one patch or should I just paint/texture it and move on?

[image: ! 3 Patches]

Comment: Just my opinion, but what you have there is going to be fine after sanding and texturing. One patch or three doesn't really matter for the final outcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those patches are not ready for paint *or* texture. You (or your hired hand) need to properly finish the taping work. It all needs to be feathered out at *least* 10" from the repair joints using a wide knife, then sanded.

The nature of the patch is largely irrelevant. I may have done something very similar to this. The finishing work is the same in either case.

You want the transition from joint compound to existing texture perfectly smooth. That's the only way you hide this. Really, the entire patch repair area should be scraped flat before you begin. It's very difficult to skim over bumps. Focus sanding on the edges, and be sure you can't see a line where the compound ends. When you're done you won't even be able to tell how many patches there were. It'll be one wide, smooth white repair.

To answer your question directly, **neither**. Finish the taping, *then* texture.

Answer (score 2):

Its a catch 22 here.  making one neat patch, ( with straight lines) will not be as strong as what has been currently done.

Obviously, the person doing this did not worry about finish, since you have a finishing texture that is somewhat of a "stucco" type finish.

best would have been to replace the entire board. but if this person was tasked to fix the patch, one would hope they also apply the same finish to hide the work.

That Finishing effect is pretty difficult to match exactally, I would say your bigger problem is getting someone to match the finish.

Comment: "Strong"? How is that relevant? Also, acoustical texture doesn't hide poor taping. Side light from windows will make poor work pop right out.

Comment: I don't know anyone who would replace a 4x12 sheet for this work. And it's not a "stucco type" finish. It's simple sprayed texture that can easily be replicated.

Comment: @isherwood - yeah. not the best wording.. but i meant that, a single seam would develop cracks more easily. ( thats what was meant by strong) - and yes, i dont know what to call that spray finish.. but you must acknowledge that there are a few different types... im simply saying, it needs to be matched.